# Chrome Extension to retrieve page number from google docs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create a chrome extension that gets the page number of a pdf on google docs and sends an alert with the page number with the aim of eventually storing and displaying it.

The problem that I am having is that the alert, rather than displaying the page number in the alert, displays the text `[object HTMLCollection]`.

This is the javascript I used in the content.js file:

```
const pgnum = document.getElementsByClassName("div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-DARUcf-NnAfwf-cQYSPc")
alert(pgnum)
```

my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PT Pro",
  "description": "Can't be bothered with this bit yet",
  "version": "1",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://drive.google.com/file/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my popup file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers :)